# How to color specified text in c++

Tags: c++, colors

How to color specific text in c++? like:
This **is** example.
In above i want to color "is". how can i do that?

Comment: what is the relation of sound with color?

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to have much to do with the content of your question. One is talking about sound and the other is (as far as I can tell) talking about coloring console output. Please clarify the relation between these two things, or pick one to ask about. As it is, your question is about to be closed as *unclear what you're asking.*

Comment: sorry i will correct it

Comment: help out now kindly..!

Comment: Though you're now referring to a single problem, this post still lacks important details to narrow down said problem to a point where it's answerable. *Where* are you outputting text that you want to color? In a Unix terminal? In Windows' command prompt? A GUI? If you're referring to a GUI what framework are you using?

Comment: Furthermore, note that your original post made it so unclear what you were asking that there are now two answers responding to a question that is no longer present--You should *probably* ask another question instead of editing this one, **but only once you figure out how to ask your question (the text coloration question) in a clear way that doesn't leave room for confusion** -- a good start is making sure those questions I just asked in the previous comment are answered in your post.

Answer (score 2):

"C++ is a language"... saying "How to play sound in c++ or add sound in c++" doesn't make sense by itself. In order to play a sound, you need an operating system API. So what happens is: with C++ you access the operating system API (the one specific you are working like Windows, Mac, Linux) and then play the sound.

However, there are solutions (wrappers) around the operating system API's that will make this job easier for you. For example SDL Framework is platform independent, because it will deal with the operating system for you. (works for Windows, Mac, Linux, etc)

This is a sample of playing sound using SDL2 Framework. Take a look at [this code example for SDL 2](https://gist.github.com/armornick/3447121) (without SDL_mixer) or [this tutorial for SDL 1.2](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/guideaudioexamples.html) (which has the same functions for the audio part):

```
static Uint8 *audio_chunk;
static Uint32 audio_len;
static Uint8 *audio_pos;

/* The audio function callback takes the following parameters:
   stream:  A pointer to the audio buffer to be filled
   len:     The length (in bytes) of the audio buffer
*/
void fill_audio(void *udata, Uint8 *stream, int len)
{
    /* Only play if we have data left */
    if ( audio_len == 0 )
        return;

    /* Mix as much data as possible */
    len = ( len > audio_len ? audio_len : len );
    SDL_MixAudio(stream, audio_pos, len, SDL_MIX_MAXVOLUME);
    audio_pos += len;
    audio_len -= len;
}

/* Load the audio data ... */

;;;;;

audio_pos = audio_chunk;

/* Let the callback function play the audio chunk */
SDL_PauseAudio(0);

/* Do some processing */

;;;;;

/* Wait for sound to complete */
while ( audio_len > 0 ) {
    SDL_Delay(100);         /* Sleep 1/10 second */
}
SDL_CloseAudio();
```

Again, this is just a sample. Maybe you just want to play a "wave" file without worry about wave buffers, etc, etc...

On Windows, for example, you have the `PlaySound()` function. With this, you can just give the filename (.wav) and that's it.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx

For other platforms, something similiar may exist... good luck ;-)

Comment: The code reference uses the old SDL-1.2 library. SDL2 should be preferred always.

Comment: I think this part of API didn't change... again, my answer is just some generic sample and should not be taken as a concrete specific solution. The goal is to show that "there are APIs for this" ;-)

Comment: thanks for editing ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that (playing sounds) in *standard* [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++14), since the standard does not know about sound-related things. You need some extra (often operating system specific) library, such as [SFML](http://sfml-dev.org/) or [Qt](http://qt.io/); both can run on several systems and are abstracting [operating-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific services.

If you are using [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to a terminal, you might try the [BELL character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character).

Notice that your user might not even have any way to hear sounds (e.g. lack of -or disabled- speakers on his computer, or deaf user).